# Excel show value as it was on save instead of #NAME if formula is unknown

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

We are using accounting software that has an Excel plugin that allows us to fetch data from their database. The way they do this is by adding special formulas that we can use in Excel, for example:

Excel with special formulas:
[image: Excel with special formulas]

The problem now is that, when opening an Excel sheet that was prepared like this on another device that does not have this plugin installed, the values are no longer readable: Excel doesn't recognize the formula and thus shows a #NAME error.

As a workaround currently we save every Excel we create like this twice: once with the formulas and once where we pasted all sheets "as values". Of course this is a cumbersome process.

What I was wondering:

- Is there any way to teach Excel to show the values as they were when the sheet was last saved? For example, if you make a data connection to some database, and somebody else later opens the file that has no access to the database, Excel can also show the values as they were upon the last connection; just this doesn't seem to work with formulas then?
- If this is not possible, is there some easy VBA that we could link to a button in the ribbon, that saves a copy of the current workbook (with all sheets) with values-only, so without the formulas? Then it's still a manual process to click that button but at least we don't have to copy-paste as values sheet per sheet anymore...

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I would look at the workbook_open event, Consider showing a message telling to first install the plugin before opening. On your second question: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately installing the plugin isn't enough. Not all users have access to the data source the plugin needs etc. So I guess we're stuck with option 2 then. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would work with user defined functions.... possible disable "Update links to other documents" in the Advanced options.  Pretty certain it wouldn't work.

For your second question I can think of two ways to do it.
Either go through each sheet, copy *all* the cells and paste values back:

```
Sub PlaceValues()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = ThisWorkbook 'This is the file containing the code.
                             'You could change it to look at some other open workbook.
    
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    For Each wrksht In wrkBk.Worksheets
        With wrksht
            .Cells.Copy
            .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
    Next wrksht
    
End Sub
```

A more targeted approach would be to replace the specified formula.
One downfall here would be replacing `SUM` formula would also replace `SUMIF` as it contains the text SUM.

```
Public Sub Test()

    ReplaceFormula "FIN_G_EN"
    ReplaceFormula "SUM"

End Sub

Public Sub ReplaceFormula(FormulaText As String)

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    For Each wrksht In wrkBk.Worksheets
        Dim rFound As Range
        With wrksht.Cells
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=FormulaText, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               LookAt:=xlPart, _
                               MatchCase:=True)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                Do
                    rFound.Value = rFound.Value
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing
            End If
        End With
    
    Next wrksht

End Sub
```

Comment: Feel free to tick it as the accepted answer if it works for you.